# How to call a loop from a subroutine and call another subroutine into the called loop subroutine

Tags: vb.net

Here I am trying to call a subroutine which contains a swapping formula (named as logic) into another subroutine which contains a loop statement directly into the main routine.

I dont want to call the swapping formula into the loop subroutine.

What I want to do is create a loop subroutine which i can use again and again in the main routine for different subroutines.

```
Module Module1
Dim x, y As Integer
Sub Main()
    calling2(AddressOf forloop , (calling3(AddressOf logic))))
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

As you can guess this doesnt work and i cant call a subroutine in a subroutine in a main routine. I want to know how it can be done.
The rest of my code is down below if anyone wants to read it for more understanding of my problem

```
Function myswap(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer)
    x = x + y
    y = x - y
    x = x - y

End Function
```

Below now is my loop subroutine. I want this to stay as it is so I can use it multiple times without altering its own code.

```
Sub forloop()
    Dim i As Integer
    Console.WriteLine("enter how many times to be repeated?")
    Dim c As Integer = Console.ReadLine
    For i = 1 To c

    Next


End Sub
```

Below here are my calling subroutines which i am using to call subroutines into the main routine. If I just call a single subroutine then mu program works e.g.
I say calling(AddressOf logic)
This works perfectly but when i call them both together then i get the error

Error   BC30057 Too many arguments to 'Public Function calling2(ByRef b As Action) As Object

```
Function calling(ByRef a As Action)
    a()

End Function

Function calling2(ByRef b As Action , ByRef n As Action)


End Function

Function logic()
    Console.Write("enter first number:")
    x = Console.ReadLine
    Console.Write("enter second number:")
    y = Console.ReadLine
    Console.Write(x)
    Console.Write("  ,   ")
    Console.WriteLine(y)

End Function

Sub myswap(x, y)
    Console.WriteLine("after swapping:")
    Console.Write(x)
    Console.Write("  ,   ")
    Console.WriteLine(y)
End Sub

Function calling3(ByRef k As Action)

End Function


End Module
```

Comment: Pro tip: In your project settings - turn option strict and option explicit ON, then follow the compiler warnings.  It will improve your code 10000%

Comment: Also (sub)routines are called methods - and dont give up mate you will get there.  Thanks :)